# Word used for sighing before doing something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, John is about lift something heavy. He blows some air and proceeds to pick it up. Would there be a word for that specific action? I've tried 'sighed', but it didn't really fit.

Comment: *Takes a deep breath*, perhaps. Not a single word, I know, but it provides the emphasis that *sigh* lacks.

Comment: I don't know who voted this down but, apart from asking for a single word, this seems to be a reasonable question.

Comment: "Anticipirespirate", perhaps? : )

Comment: Exasperated? Sigh.

Answer (score 3):

Exhale -  to breathe out in a deliberate manner

Definition given on search for [Exhale define](https://www.google.com/search?q=Exhale+define)

*[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Exhale)* gives this sentence in its thesaurus  entry  for *Exhale*:

> exhale - expel air; "Exhale when you lift the weight"